# Why do tuples not get unused variable warnings?

Tags: c++

In the following example, compiling with `-Wall`, some of the unused variables are not warned about:

```
#include <tuple>

struct Foo
{
    int a, b;
};

struct Bar
{
    ~Bar() {}

    int a, b;
};

int three() { return 3; }

int main()
{
    Foo f0 {1, 2};
    Foo f1 {three(), 2};
    Bar b0 {1, 2};
    Bar b1 {three(), 2};
    std::tuple<int, int> p0 {1, 2};
    std::tuple<int, int> p1 {three(), 2};
}
```

- clang 12.0.1: `b`s and `p1` don't get warnings
- gcc 11.2: `b`s and `p`s don't get warnings

Why don't these get warnings? Is there a way to mark the destructor of `Bar` such that it won't mask the warnings?

Comment: Tradeoffs. Consider the case of something like [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). Warnings would be undesirable for something like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler will do its best to flag unused variables, but this is difficult for non-trivial types, and both `Bar` and `std::tuple<int, int>` are non-trivial.

```
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<Foo>);
static_assert(!std::is_trivial_v<Bar>);
static_assert(!std::is_trivial_v<std::tuple<int, int>>);
```

As is described in

- [Bug 55203 - No unused warning for variables of non-trivial types](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55203)

> As the compiler cannot tell for sure in some cases, such as the ctor calling an external function, the only reasonable way of handling this I see is explicit tagging of types for which there should be an unused warning if only ctor/dtor are called for a variable. Here's my attempt at attribute warn_unused.

you could use GCC's `warn_unused` attribute if you want a `-Wunused-variable` to be emitted in case on the constructor and/or destructor of the variable of the non-trivial type is called.

```
struct __attribute__((warn_unused)) Bar {
    ~Bar() {}
    int a, b;
};

int main() {
    Bar b{1, 3}; // warning: unused variable 'b' [-Wunused-variable]
}
```

Comment: So I guess std::tuple doesn't have such an attribute because it may be a tuple of objects that are non-trivial?